# How to combine strings in list with a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

For example:

```
s = ["ab", "cd"]

# expected output ac, ad, bc, bd
# This is easy

print([i+j for i in s[0] for j in s[1]])
# ['ac', 'ad', 'bc', 'bd']
```

But when the length of list is larger than two.How to achieve that with list comprehension?

```
s = ["ab", "cd", "ef"]
```

should give `ace, acf, ade, adf, bce, bcf, bde, bdf`.(How to use for loop to achieve that if we don't use recursion?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is the product of these sequences. [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) does just this. The only complication is turning the sequences back into strings, which you can do with `join()`:

```
from itertools import product

s = ["ab", "cd", "ef"]

list(map(''.join, product(*s)))
# ['ace', 'acf', 'ade', 'adf', 'bce', 'bcf', 'bde', 'bdf']
```

You can also use a list comprehension if you prefer:

```
[''.join(t) for t in product(*s)]
```

You *can* of course do this yourself with a simple recursive function. That might look something like:

```
s = ["ab", "cd", "ef"]

def product(l):
    if len(l) == 0:
        yield ''
        return
    
    start, *rest = l
    for c in start:
        for sublist in product(rest):
            yield c + sublist

list(product(s))
# ['ace', 'acf', 'ade', 'adf', 'bce', 'bcf', 'bde', 'bdf']
```